# Octave and Java: libjvm.so not found

Tags: java, debian, octave

I am trying to use [WFDB toolbox for Matlab from Physionet](http://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/) in GNU Octave. One prerequisite is having GNU Octave 3.8.1 or later with the Java package, so I have compiled it for my Debian 7.8 and then installed Java package from within Octave. I am not sure to have correctly proceeded with compilation, I had some issues with Java interface during the configuration.

The problem is that when calling a Java method from Octave, I get this error:

```
error: javaMethod: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so:
failed to load:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked if the file exist or not, and I found out that the "client" folder does not exist. On the other hand, the "server" folder is present and I have also found

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.7/jre/lib/amd64/client
```

I cannot figure out why these files are missing, I am not a Java programmer nor GNU/Linux specialist.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: On ubuntu apparently some update since I installed octave originally caused this.  "apt-get remove octave" followed by "apt-get install octave" fixed whatever it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install the java package.  The functions in the java package have been merged into the Octave core language for the 3.8 release. You don't need to do anything, java should work out of the box for you (provided you didn't mess up while building it). If you installed the java package on your Octave 3.8 install, you are probably shadowing its own functions.

I'd recommend that you use the Octave version on the Debian repositories. You are using Debian 7 (wheezy), so you can use [wheezy-backports which already have Octave 3.8.2](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/octave). No need to faff around with building from source if you are not familiar with it and Debian already provides one for you.

Comment: Ok, now I get [error: [java] java.lang.NullPointerException], but I guess it's the fault of the toolbox... Thanks for the answer!